# Data retrieve from website are all "-"? what can I do?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to download some locate exchange rate information from the following webpage. But when I try to download data using the script below, the data become "-". How can I get the right value? Thanks.

[(1. screen capture from webpage directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSf1X.png)

[(2. screen capture from webpage downloaded by google app script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar2sT.png)

```
function Exchange() {


  // Google Drive Parameters
  var Google_DRive_ID = 'YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Google_DRive_ID);  
  FileName[1] = "Webpage.txt';

  // download front page information  
  var root = "https://hk.ttrate.com/en_us/?b=0&c=JPY&s=1&t=1"  
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root,{muteHttpExceptions: true})
  var rc = data.getResponseCode();

  if (rc == 200) {
    folder.createFile(FileName[1], data)    
  }

}
```

Comment: In my environment, the HTML file from the URL is created using your script. Can I ask you about ``the data become "-"``?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I am new to google app script and I have no idea why the data become "-". However, please feel free to express your thinking here.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, in my environment, I cannot reproduce your situation. Is the script in your question the same with the script retrieved such result? If it is difference, could you please tell me about it?

Comment: It is the same except 'YOUR_GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID' which should be you own google folder id.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, the created file has HTML strings from the URL. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your situation yet. I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it looks like you are doing is downloading the HTML source of the URL you've specified, then trying to render the locally stored copy of said source.

That will not work as most of the resources linked to within the HTML are relative links, causing the browser to try to fetch them from the same location as the HTML file you've created.

Trying to scrape a site like this is a difficult way to go about this.

If you're interested in getting exchange rates programmatically, use a service that's explicitly for that purpose.

From [a simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=api%20for%20exchange%20rates), you can find numerous services that provide an HTTP API for exchange rate data (many of which offering a free access tier). Using such APIs, you'll probably get a JSON response which is [easy to parse in the Apps Script environment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json).

Comment: Hi chuckx, thanks for your direction. I don't have much knowledge on API and the term "JSON". I think I need further search on them. Thanks you very much.

Comment: An API is an interface that is intended to be interacted with programmatically and JSON is a data interchange format that's easy to parse (as opposed to attempting to extract the values you're interested out of a complicated HTML document).